# WooCommerce and jQuery Payment

Tags: woocommerce, payment-gateway

I am trying to validate a custom credit card form using [jQuery Payment](https://github.com/stripe/jquery.payment) (which actually comes bundled with WooCommerce) as soon as the checkout form is submitted.

First of all, if I enqueue my script in head, the formatting/validation doesn't work at all as WooCommerce loads the gateways after the DOM is ready using AJAX. ***If I put the code inline, the format fields works, but not the validation***. Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // Format Card Number, Expiry Date and CVV
    $('#pld-ccnum').payment('formatCardNumber');
    $('#pld-ccexp').payment('formatCardExpiry');
    $('#pld-cvv').payment('formatCardCVC');

    // Validate fields before submitting the checkout form
    $("form.checkout]").submit(function( event ) {
        var valid = $.payment.validateCardNumber($("#pld-ccnum").val());
        if (!valid) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            $("#pld-ccnum").focus().css({"border-color":"#e54747"});
        }
    });                     

});
```

What I am doing wrong? I am enqueuing the scripts from outside of my gateway class.

```
function pc_wc_pld_gayeway_enqueue() {

    if ( is_checkout() ) {

        wp_register_script( 'payline', plugins_url( 'js/payline.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery-payment' ), '1.0' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'payline' );

        wp_register_style( 'payline', plugins_url( 'css/payline.css', __FILE__ ), array(), '1.0', 'all' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'payline' );
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pc_wc_pld_gayeway_enqueue', 15 );
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Hi, I'm having a similar issue. Did you resolve this?

Comment: Yes, I did. What exactly you are looking for? Formatting the card fields or validation?

Comment: I found a solution by hooking in to Woocommerce's `checkout_place_order_{gateway}` event. I needed to tokenize credit cards :)